# Bash-скрипт для установки программ и python библиотек

Tags: python, bash, pip

Привет. Пытаюсь написать простейший bash-скрипт для моего приложения, чтобы все зависимости устанавливались в одну команду. Но ничего не получается, возникают ошибки:

```
] is not understood in combination with the other options.
```

и

```
Collecting pip3
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3
```

Сам код bash-скрипта:

```
apt install python3 -y
apt install python3-pip -y
apt install git -y
pip3 install --upgrade pip3
pip3 install requests netaddr
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

Почему возникают эти ошибки и с чем они связаны?

Comment: `#!/bin/sh`, а точно `apt`, а не `apt-get` ?

Comment: Совершенно точно `apt`

Comment: метка абсолютно не «в тему»: к программе bash приведённые сообщения имеют отношения не больше, чем, например, к клавиатуре, с помощью которой писались эти команды. вводите их по отдельности и увидите, какая вызвала данные сообщения.

Comment: Потому что pip3 install --upgrade pip

Comment: @andreymal так, а в чем собсна проблема?

Comment: В том, что не существует пакета pip3, существует только pip

Comment: @andreymal всё, понял.